# Using 'mutually exclusive' null check involving multiple columns hibernate constraint

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider three tables. Interest date can come from Master document or Manual Override. If it from Master Document, the master_doc_id carries the reference and if it comes from manual override manual_override_id carries the reference

```
    INTEREST_RATE
    id,
    rate,
    master_doc_id,
    manual_override_id

    MASTER_DOC
    id,
    <Master doc related fields>

    MANUAL_OVERRIDE
    id,
    <Manual Overide related fields>
```

Interest rate comes from either Master doc or manual override. Meaning, either one can have an id, and the other null. Never will both have values, or will both be null

Both MasterDoc and ManualOverride provide one-to-many mapping to Interest

MasterDoc

```
    <set access="field" name="interestRates" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <key column="MASTER_DOC_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.foo.foos.InterestRate"/>
    </set>
```

ManualOverRide

```
    <set access="field" name="interestRates" inverse="false" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <key column="MANUAL_OVERRIDE_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.foo.foos.InterestRate"/>
    </set>
```

This works fine.

But, i need to enforce the contstraint that, either of them has to have a value and the other null.

I tried.

1. Obvious not-null in one-to-many mapping. Obvious that this will fail because, both columns cant have values together.
2. Constraint on the table, (in the database). But, hibernate creates an insert followed by an update on the table. Even though the final result would be valid, the constraint will fail after the initial insert.

ex:

while uploading the initial file

```
 insert into master_doc......
 insert into interest_rate.... (with null values in master_doc_id and manual_override_id)
 update interest_rate (set master_doc_id = id of master_doc)
```

The constraint fails on line no 2.

Any way I can get this to work. I need to have this constraint in place, to prevent manual updates on the table.